# How to align box on the dropdown menu?

Tags: css, google-chrome, joomla, developer-tools

I'm trying to make a site, doing what I know, and learning something I need.

My site is: http://dhems.x10.mx/home/

It's based on Joomla, And I wanna learn one thing, how can I center the box of dropdown menu "layouts", I saw on developer tools on chrome that "-webkit-transform: translate (-50%)" are strikethrough on ".mega-align-center" but I don't know what to do!!

ps: in the backend it's centered, only on frontend not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the class `.t3-megamenu .mega-align-center>.dropdown-menu` (line 1672)  value to `left: -246px;` would od the trick as it is the half of the container width minus the width of the navigation link.

Comment: Very good @jacek_podwysocki! It's all good! do you know why "-webkit-transform: translate (-50%)" was strikethrough? Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad it works, please mark the answer as accepted ;) -webkit-transform was strikethrough as webkit-transform was already in the css file with the value of scale(1, 0)